# Have Selenium quit Chrome driver when browser window/tabs are closed. MacOS/Python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm trying to write a piece of code for work using Selenium on Python, thats intended to run on MacOS. The function of the code is to parse a text file for strings, open a new Chrome window, and search each line from the text file on a new tab (showing only results from yesterday onwards).

The problem is, it does all of that fine, but when I go to manually close the browser/tabs, the process is still running in the dock/taskbar. Now, the people I'm pushing this out to are all savvy enough to be able to right-click -> quit the process, but I want it to function as similarly to a normal browser window as possible.

The versions of everything I'm using are as follows:

- Python: 3.11.1
- Selenium: 4.7.2
- MacOS: Monterey 12.4
- Chrome: 108.0.5359.124
- The latest version of Chromedriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException
from contextlib import suppress
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import sys
import urllib3

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


today = date.today()
print(today)
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterdaystr = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(yesterdaystr)


file = open("testdoc.txt", "r")
filelist = file.readlines()

for i in range(len(filelist)):
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
           filelist[i] +
           " after:" +
           yesterdaystr +
           "&start=")
    if i < (len(filelist) - 1):
        driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
```

Many of the imports are legacy from testing various things.
I've tried listening for various variables like driver.current_window_handle, driver.window_handles, driver.getCurrentUrl() to see if they come up as 0 or None, and then running driver.quit() when that occurs, all to no avail, at best they work occasionally and under specific circumstances. Take for example:

```py
while True:
    if len(driver.window_handles) == 0:
        driver.quit()
        break
```

This works maybe 1/10 times, and that's only if I close the browser almost immediately after the last tab loads. It feels like no matter what loop I put at the end to catch some event that signifies that the window has been closed, it only wants to run for a second or two at best. Is it possible there's something preventing an infinite loop from running properly with my setup?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @AbiSaran, I'm expecting it to detect when there are no more window_handles associated with the driver, and then run quit() to kill the process

Answer (score 1):

`driver.quit():` The `quit()` method quits the driver, **closing every associated** **window**.

`driver.close():` The `close()` **method closes the currently focused window**, quitting the driver if the current window is the only open window. If there are no windows open, it will error out.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/selenium-webdriver-quick/9781789612486/17ecb01f-a69b-45cb-86f2-f081b7f6a472.xhtml

If you not have windows handle to associated , nothing going to works.

`if len(driver.window_handles) > 0` it's going to works.

You can change too :

```
if len(driver.window_handles) > 0:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Part of the problem that I failed to mention is that I've also tried


`if len(driver.window_handles) == 1`


And that still only fires within the first second or so of loading the last tab

Comment: You can change to close and  use exeption in the error too